# Evaluating a limit with sum

Tags: limits

How may one evaluate:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n-2}\left[1+\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} \left(1-\left(1-\frac{2}{i}\right)^{n-2}\right)\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{(n-2)(i-1)}\right)^{n-2}\right)\right]$$

Comment: The first factor $(1-2/n)^{n-2}$ approaches $e^{-2}$.  Is the second exponent $n-2$ supposed to be outside one pair of brackets?

Comment: @Michael Edited for clarity. You're correct on the part that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}(1-2/n)^{n-2}=e^{-2}$. I suspect the limit posed in the question approaches $1$ on numerical grounds.

Comment: This limit popped up in a problem where $\mathbb{R}^n$ was to be completely covered by special $n$-cubes.

Comment: The last factor still looks like $(1-(1-u))$ where $u$ is a $n-2$ power.  So presumably not what is meant (as Michael suggests).

Comment: Oops... fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above, the first of the factors approaches $e^{-2}$.
The first of the two factors inside the sum stays between 1 and $1-e^{-2}$.
The second of the two factors looks like $1-\exp(-1/(i-1))$.  Since most of the terms are for large $i$, near $n$, this is roughly $1/(i-1)$.  When you sum that, it looks like $c+\log n$
So I expect the answer to be $e^{-2}(1+A\log n + B)$, for some A between 1 and $1-e^{-2}$,
and some constant $B$.

Comment: For $n=460$, the above expression evaluated to approximately $0.95$ and the increase was asymptotic ($n=460$ was the best I could do using Wolfram).

Comment: Can we determine exactly what $A$ and $B$ are for the limit?

Comment: My formula predicts that, if you do $n=25,50,100,200,400$ the answer increases by a constant amount each time.  Each doubling of $n$ would make the answer increase by $e^{-2}A\log 2$.

Comment: Ahhh so it diverges...